# The screen becomes a Blur on Android Lollipop devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-5.0-lollipop

The code which worked for lower versions of android preior to 5.0 now on android lollipop devices are showing screens like these

[image]

Even on updating my code to the 5.0 android toolbar, material theme effects.
these screens are totally mibehaving in some screens like

**On Back press from one fragment to the previous one,**
**On loading listview**

Comment: does your code do something with display or have gradient image?

Comment: I have already seen some artifacts like this when trying to reload an activity/fragment that has already been loaded... but can't help you on how to fix that :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with loading the content from the WebView
So if the screen is becoming blur its probably because of loading dinamic content from google play services like ***MAPS or from server using WebView.***

**The Fix I opted to is View level Hardware Acceleration**

```
webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE,null);
```

for more refer this link [Check this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html)